# JavaScript behaving weirdly (maybe due to its asynchronous nature)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this piece of code in JS as described below

```
for (id in ids) {
    if (id needs to be called) {
        console.log(id);  // statement 1
        $http.post('someEndpoint', {id : id}).then(function success(response) {
            console.log(id);  // statement 2
            someDataStructure[id].data = response.data;
        });
    }
}
```

Assuming `ids = [1, 2, 3]`, at statement 1, `1 2 3` is printed on the console. At statement 2, `3 3 3` is printed. This is obviously less than ideal and I am losing data for `1 2`. Also, I must add that the endpoint is getting requests for `1 2 3`, so at this point, I am really confused. It would be great if someone could throw some light and help me understand how to fix this.

Comment: If `ids` is an array, use `for (let index in ids)`, and then `let id = ids[index]`.

Comment: If `ids` is an array, you shouldn't be using `for-in`. Change it to `ids.forEach(function(id) { ... })` and you're set.

Comment: @squint Yeah, I know that issue, that's why I said "make sure to call the `id`, not index of `id`. To avoid confusion, I modified my answer. Using ES6 `let`, we can get rid of closures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap `id` in a [closure function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example):

```
for (id in ids) {
    (function(id) {
        if (id needs to be called) {
            console.log(id);  // statement 1
            $http.post('someEndpoint', {id : id}).then(function success(response) {
                console.log(id);  // statement 2
                someDataStructure[id].data = response.data;
            });
        }
    })(id);
}
```

You could also simply use a `forEach` loop, which will automatically make the closure:

```
ids.forEach(function(id) {
    if (/*id needs to be called*/) {
        console.log(id);  // statement 1
        $http.post('someEndpoint', {id : id}).then(function success(response) {
            console.log(id);  // statement 2
            someDataStructure[id].data = response.data;
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it out and keep you posted :)